Flutter Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle.?

Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version
that Flutter is using for Gradle.
To fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter
by running flutter doctor --verbose.
Then, update the Gradle version specified in
/Users/mac/Documents/GitHub/salesfine/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
to be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for
more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

